# Redis Crashing in .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a weird error in Redis on .Net 6. When I run the test code here:

https://github.com/redis-developer/redis-graph-dotnet-basic-app/blob/main/Program.cs

It works perfectly fine. In this case the code is running in the program.cs file.

When I port that code to a class, in order to better manage encapsulation and complexity. It does not work. What it does is run the code and when it gets to the: await graph.QueryAsync part, it just stops the debugger. Very strange indeed.

Here is the code I am using. Any thoughts or suggestions:

```
//Program.cs (Relevant Bits)

using RedisTest //PROGRAM //WRITE TO REDIS ENTERPRISE CLOUD Process_LoadGraph process_LoadGraph = new Process_LoadGraph(); process_LoadGraph.Controller(results);


//SHARED CONNECTION CLASS
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using StackExchange.Redis;

namespace RedisTest
{
    public class RedisSharedConnection
    {
        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }

        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            ConnectionMultiplexer connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigData.dbConnectionString);
            return connectionMultiplexer;
        });


    }
}



//USAGE CLASS

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NRedisGraph;

namespace RedisTest
{
    public class Process_LoadGraph
    {
        public async void Controller(List<Result> results)
        {
            //Setup
            var redisConnection = RedisSharedConnection.Connection;

            //var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigData.dbConnectionString);
            var db = redisConnection.GetDatabase(ConfigData.dbId);
            var graph = new RedisGraph(db);
            string graphName = ConfigData.graphName;

            //Test Transaction

            // Create Bob
            // CRASHES HERE
            var createBobResult = await graph.QueryAsync("pets", "MERGE(:human{name:'Bob',age:32})");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add more context. How do you instantiate your classes?

Comment: Yes, the class is instantiated.

Comment: But how? Please show your `Program.cs`.

Comment: Please edit and add this code to the question. Please add also what kind of error/message do you have.

Comment: I have edited as requested. Please note there is no error message the IDE just stops executing the code.

Comment: Still I don't know if you have a console application, asp.net core api or mayby WPF app. Also I don't know how do you call `Controller` method from `Process_LoadGraph`. If your app hangs, then it could be some deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution is to use Redis in a static class. Along the following lines:

```
    internal static class WriteToDB
    {
        public static async Task WriteAsync(List<string> querieS)
        {
            //Load Graph

            //Setup
            var redisConnection = RedisSharedConnection.Connection;

            //var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(ConfigData.dbConnectionString);
            var db = redisConnection.GetDatabase(ConfigData.dbId);
            var graph = new RedisGraph(db);
            string graphName = ConfigData.graphName;

            // ** DEBUG

            //Test Transaction
            // Create Bob
            var createBobResult = await graph.QueryAsync("pets", "MERGE(:human{name:'Bob',age:32})");
            { }

            //Clear Graph
            await graph.QueryAsync(graphName, "MATCH(n) DETACH DELETE n");
            { }
        }
    }
```